# When transferring Files Via TCP in Java, It doesnt transfer the whole image even if i specify byte size greater than the image

Tags: java, image, sockets, tcp, byte

I have got this TCP Client Server Model, It works and transfers the files to the destination. However, when I open the image it is never the full image. It is half or maybe just over half. Here is my current code:

Receiver:

```
try {
        byte[] b = new byte[200000];
        Socket sr = new Socket("192.168.192.41", 30481);
        InputStream is = sr.getInputStream();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\tproudfoot\\Desktop\\Photo.png");
        is.read(b, 0, 200000);
        fos.write(b, 0, 200000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Sender:

```
try {
        File f = new File(Path);
        long size = f.length();
        System.out.println(size);
        ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(30481);
        Socket sr = s.accept();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(Path);
        byte[] b = new byte[200000];
        fis.read(b, 0, 200000);
        OutputStream os = sr.getOutputStream();
        os.write(b, 0, 200000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I Have set the byte size to 200000 so I know that it isn't undercutting the photo. In the sender class i have a line that find the size of the chosen file. So i know that the byte size is way over that. I also tried setting byte size to the exact file size but that didn't work either

thanks in advance

Comment: try to add `os.flush()` at the end of the sender.

Comment: just tried adding flush to the bottom of both classes, same output. an unfinished image. @JohannesKuhn

Comment: What is the result of the line `is.read(b, 0, 200000);`? Is it your photo size? Also, if you use Java 9 or higher, consider using `in.transferTo(sr.getOutputStream())`. Otherwise, read and write the streams in a loop.

Comment: `read()` returns the number of bytes actually read.  You need to use that size when `write()`'ing the buffer afterwards. And you need to call `read()` in a loop until you have read the full image, if it is larger than your buffer. Also, since you are sending the image over a TCP socket, you should send the image's size in bytes before sending the actual bytes, so the receiver knows how many bytes to expect and when to stop reading, so it can read and buffer effectively.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn the output of "is.Read(b, 0 , 200000)" is "68929", Windows tells me the iamage size is "172,032". Any chance you would be able to show me a rough example of what this for loop should look like? I am new to sockets so this is all a bit out of my depth currently. Thanks for all the help so far!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 9 or higher, you can use [`InputStream.transferTo(OutputStream out)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#transferTo(java.io.OutputStream)):

```
is.transferTo(fos);
```

If you use an older Java version, here is the source code of the `transferTo` method:

```
public long transferTo(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    Objects.requireNonNull(out, "out");
    long transferred = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
    int read;
    while ((read = this.read(buffer, 0, DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)) >= 0) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        transferred += read;
    }
    return transferred;
}
```

`MAX_BUFFER_SIZE` is 8192.
You basically have to do the same while loop. You might not need to count the bytes transferred, so you could leave this out.

So your both examples would look like:

```
try {
    Socket sr = new Socket("192.168.192.41", 30481);
    InputStream is = sr.getInputStream();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\tproudfoot\\Desktop\\Photo.png");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    while ((read = is.read(buffer, 0 buffer.length)) >= 0) {
        fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and

```
try {
    File f = new File(Path);
    long size = f.length();
    System.out.println(size);
    ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(30481);
    Socket sr = s.accept();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(Path);
    OutputStream os = sr.getOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int read;
    while ((read = fis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0) {
        os.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: much appreciated, i will take a look tomorrow morning. Thanks for all the help everyone!